# What's this ellipsis in c++ : #define MBGL_DEFINE_ENUM(T, values...)?

Tags: c++, syntax, macros

While trying to build mapboxgl-native with msvc 2017, I had errors with the following construct in their [enum.hpp](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/f648cfeef6544755fdb10c3cf8847e878d70e0ff/include/mbgl/util/enum.hpp#L19)

`#define MBGL_DEFINE_ENUM(T, values...)`

This macro is used like [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/4577c56745d90cfa00837d00e5e5605260a54879/src/mbgl/util/event.cpp#L6)

I could not find the documentation for this c++ syntax.

Which version of c++ defines this ellipsis construct ? How is it called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't standard C++. The standard way would not name the ellipsis. [It's a GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros).

Variadic macros in standard C++ look somewhat like this:

```
#define foo(arg, ...) arg __VA_ARGS__
```

Where `__VA_ARGS__` stands for all the arguments in the ellipsis.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the doc also mention some 'comma' restriction lifted in upcoming C++2a, could it be it ?

Comment: @rotoglup - The document elaborates on the C++2a changes. And no, naming the pack is not related to it. It's still an extension.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess that's not 100% clear to me, but your answer helps :)